# Does the existence of a non-trivial finite etale cover imply non-trivial etale fundumental group?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, etale-cohomology

Suppose we can find a non-trivial finite etale cover for a connected scheme $X$. Does that imply that etale fundamental group of $X$ is non-trivial?

Comment: What is your definition of etale fundamental group? If $Y\to X$ is a finite etale cover, assuming $X$ is integral, the Galois closure of $k(X)\subset k(Y)$ gives an etale Galois cover $Y'\to Y\to X$. The etale fundamental group in my understanding maps on to this Galois group and thus non-trivial.